# what is the best way to store and count duplicates of an string or integer?

Tags: c++

This code explains what I want to do:

```
unsigned long g_PlayerIP[MAX_AMOUNT_OF_PLAYERS];//save the IP address of each player
int g_max_ip = MAX_CONNECTED_FROM_ONE_IP;

PLUGIN_EXPORT bool PLUGIN_CALL OnPlayerConnect(int playerid)
{
    PlayerLoopList.push_back(playerid);

    char szIP[32];
    GetPlayerIp(playerid,szIP);//get the ip of the player into szIP
    unsigned short explodeIP[4];//declare 4 eight bit variables, to store the exploded ip
    sscanf(szIP, " %d[^.].%d[^.].%d[^.].%d", &explodeIP[0], &explodeIP[1], &explodeIP[2], &explodeIP[3]);//explode ip into 4 pats ranging from 0 to 255
    g_PlayerIP[playerid] = (explodeIP[0] + (explodeIP[1] << 8) + (explodeIP[2] << 16) + (explodeIP[3] << 24));//store the ip as a 32bit integer
    int connected = 0;//variable for counting connected players fron one ip
    for(list <int>::iterator i = PlayerLoopList.begin(); i != PlayerLoopList.end(); ++i)
    {
        if(g_PlayerIP[playerid] == g_PlayerIP[*i])
        {
            ++connected;
        }
    }
    if(connected >= g_max_ip)
    {
        Report(playerid,IP_FLOOD,g_PlayerIP[playerid]);//too many connected from one ip, report it.
    }
    return true;
}
```

and seeing this part:

```
    sscanf(szIP, " %d[^.].%d[^.].%d[^.].%d", &explodeIP[0], &explodeIP[1], &explodeIP[2], &explodeIP[3]);//explode ip into 4 pats ranging from 0 to 255
    g_PlayerIP[playerid] = (explodeIP[0] + (explodeIP[1] << 8) + (explodeIP[2] << 16) + (explodeIP[3] << 24));//store the ip as a 32bit integer
    int connected = 0;//variable for counting connected players fron one ip
    for(list <int>::iterator i = PlayerLoopList.begin(); i != PlayerLoopList.end(); ++i)
    {
        if(g_PlayerIP[playerid] == g_PlayerIP[*i])
        {
            ++connected;
        }
    }
```

makes me a bit, well, questioning me about if it can be done faster, there has to be a superb way in c++?

Comment: Counting the number of elements in a container is easy with `std::count`.

Comment: but then i would need to create 2^32 containers (1 for each unique ip)! I mean storing and counting the connected IP's.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use std::map. That way you don't need one for every possible ip, only the ips you're actually using.

```
std::map<int, unsigned int> counts;

counts[playerid]++;
if (counts[playid] >= g_max_ip){ //Report
}
```